# Install Boost.Compute on Mac OS

Tags: boost, opencl, boost-compute

I'm following [this link](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost_compute/getting_started.html#boost_compute.getting_started.installation) and trying to install Boost Compute on Mac OS. It says it can be installed with `make install` but I cannot find a Makefile.

I added the path to the boost-compute folder to the header search path in the Xcode project. But now boost-compute is dependent on boost in my computer, and cannot link to the boost already installed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, it says it's a header-only library that requires no compilation. It also says that :

> Boost.Compute is a header-only library, so no linking is required. To use the library just add the include directory to the compilation flags and link with the system's OpenCL library.

Comment: Thanks. I posted more info in my question. "I added the path to the boost-compute folder to the header search path in the Xcode project. But now boost-compute is dependent on boost in my computer, and cannot link to the boost already installed." So I think I should install the boost-compute to get it working.